# How safe is data stored in an iPhone app on the App Store?

Tags: iphone, security, encryption

I know that app binaries are encrypted and signed during the build process when packaging up for the app store, but I'm wondering how safe the data in the bundle is?    For example, have there been cases of people being able to read strings (or worse encryption keys..) out of iPhone apps?

I'm looking into making a game with a prize - and it's going to be a bit pointless if the winner was able to crack the game and win the prize without even playing the game.

Any advice would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Related, some insights applicable here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006022/securely-provide-a-unique-secret-code-to-winner-of-flash-game

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what "the prize" is? Is a code to a website or something used in gameplay?

Comment: You might want to check whether your prize is allowed by Apple's store guidelines.

Comment: @martin Thanks, some really useful stuff in that link. Sounds like it's pretty tricky to get right!

Comment: -1 you are bad at searching aren't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone apps have been successfully reverse engineered, so yes, there are examples which show that the encryption of app bundles (and hence their content) is not bulletproof.

See [this link](http://dvlabs.tippingpoint.com/blog/2009/03/06/reverse-engineering-iphone-appstore-binaries) for one such example.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider any app insecure, an App Store distributed app is total insecure as Apple protects iOS data, but jailbreak is a common and easy task, so anyone can search inside your app.

I suggest you to don't store any valuable data on an iOS app.

Comment: Sensitive data needs to be kept on a server somewhere.  Especially for a prize scenario like the OP mentions.

Comment: I agree with @Jonathan.Peppers

Answer (score 0):

Images, text files and sound data are stored in a completely "unsafe" manner inside an iOS app bundle (unless you include your own encryption).
All one needs to do is to unzip the .ipa file.

Comment: -1 "unless you include your own encryption".  I'm sorry but there is no place to hide anything on the iphone which includes an encryption key.

Comment: You don't HAVE TO store the key on the same device.